# Accuracy for each probability cutoff in a binary classification problem (python sklearn accuracy)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

Imagine a binary classification problem. Let's say I have 800,000 predicted probabilities stored in `pred_test`. I define a `cutoff` as any value in `pred_test` such that the values that are greater than or equal to `cutoff` are assigned the value 1 and the values that are smaller than `cutoff` are assigned the value 0.

Is there a function in `sklearn` that returns the accuracy of the model for each `cutoff` in `pred_train`? I would like to see the accuracy of the model as a function of each cutoff to systematically pick a cutoff.

I tried the following:

```py
_list = []
for cutoff in np.unique(np.sort(pred_test)):
    binary_prediction = np.where(pred_test >= cutoff, 1, 0)
    _list.append( (cutoff, binary_prediction == y_test).sum() / len(pred_test) )
```

Here, `y_test` is the ground truth (an array with the observed outcomes for each of the 800,000 rows). This code returns a list where each value contains the cutoff and its corresponding accuracy score.

The object `pred_test` has around 600,000 different values, so I am iterating 600,000 or so times. The above code is working, but it's taking a very long time to finish. Is there a more efficient way to do this? My bet is that `sklearn` already has a function that does this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is some similiar thread to check it: [Getting the maximum accuracy for a binary probabilistic classifier in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488517/getting-the-maximum-accuracy-for-a-binary-probabilistic-classifier-in-scikit-lea)

There is no built-in function for that in scikit-learn.  I think the reason why this is not implemented is that you will have the chance to overfit, you basically will tune your train set to a baseline that is risky for the test set.